# Unable to run a React-native app on the web

Tags: react-native, web

[This the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im3fr.png)
[object Object] ERROR in C:UsersAbdullahi JallowKaaraange%20Mobile%20Appassetskaaraange.png Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "C:UsersAbdullahi JallowKaaraange%20Mobile%20Appassetskaaraange.png" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme). Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default. You may need an additional plugin to handle "c:" URIs.
at C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:838:25

```
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Object.processResource (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:835:8)
    at processResource (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:825:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:969:15)
    at C:\Users\Abdullahi Jallow\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1377:12
```

web compiled with 1 error

I am trying to run this React-native app on the web but this is error I am facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question so that it is answerable. Especially the part around "helping others reproduce the problem". Some specific pieces of information that would be useful include: relevant packages/tools/frameworks to your problem, command(s) you are running and your build configuration. Also please [do not include images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). As it stands, there's not enough information in this question to help you and it is at risk of closure.